# Transpose a table result dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

so sorry but i would like to how ca do this.
I'm trying to trasnpose a table , but i have to say the tru: i don't know how

Using my query:

```
SELECT vu.fly
      ,tg.FININ fecha_ini
      ,td.BA33_DESC place
      ,tms.tms_util.getplazas_singuiachofer(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) as passengers
FROM TABLE(fnc_obtener_vuelos_guia(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO)) vu
    inner join tms.gui tg on (tg.fol = vu.fol and tg.prod = vu.producto and tg.FININ = vu.fecha_inicio)
    inner join tms.dgp td on (tg.fol = td.fol and tg.prod = td.prod)
where td.fol = :P10_FOLLETO
      and td.prod = :P10_PRODUCTO
      and tg.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO
```

the next result:

[image]

But i would like to get this:

[image]

Can somebody help me with this because is really important. Just say that the number of records/ columns will be dynamically , could be one or more

Regards

Thanks so much

Comment: Don't use images.  Show the data as *text tables* in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use conditional aggregation.  But you need a sequence to assign it.  It is not clear how you specify the ordering, so this does it alphabetically by `fly`:

```
select fecha_ini, place, passengers,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then fly end) as fly_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then fly end) as fly_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then fly end) as fly_3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then fly end) as fly_4
from (select vu.fly, tg.FININ as fecha_ini, td.BA33_DESC as place,
             tms.tms_util.getplazas_singuiachofer(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) as passengers,
             row_number() over (partition by tg.FININ, td.BA33_DESC order by vu.fly) as seqnum
      from TABLE(fnc_obtener_vuelos_guia(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO)) vu join
           tms.gui tg
           on tg.fol = vu.fol and
              tg.prod = vu.producto and 
              tg.FININ = vu.fecha_inicio join
           tms.dgp td
           on tg.fol = td.fol and
              tg.prod = td.prod
      where td.fol = :P10_FOLLETO and
            td.prod = :P10_PRODUCTO and
            tg.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO
     ) f
group by fecha_ini, place, passengers;
```

If you have another column to specify the ordering, then use that for the `order by`.

EDIT:

You might find that it is sufficient to just aggregate the data and use a string for all the `fly` values:

```
select fecha_ini, place, passengers,
       list_agg(fly, ', ') within group (order by fly) as flys
from (select vu.fly, tg.FININ as fecha_ini, td.BA33_DESC as place,
             tms.tms_util.getplazas_singuiachofer(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) as passengers
      from TABLE(fnc_obtener_vuelos_guia(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO)) vu join
           tms.gui tg
           on tg.fol = vu.fol and
              tg.prod = vu.producto and 
              tg.FININ = vu.fecha_inicio join
           tms.dgp td
           on tg.fol = td.fol and
              tg.prod = td.prod
      where td.fol = :P10_FOLLETO and
            td.prod = :P10_PRODUCTO and
            tg.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO
     ) f
group by fecha_ini, place, passengers;
```

Comment: hello @Gordon this query looks nice, but how i said , what about if i have 4 records, or 2 or 6 ... your know?, how could it be dynamically? Regards

Comment: @Julio . . . That would be a different question and would require using pl/sql, the Oracle scripting language.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the row_number as follows. but let me clear it out that pure SQL solution will generate a static number of columns, If you want to generate the dynamic number of columns then you need to use the PL/SQL solution.

SQL solution using `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT vu.fly
      ,tg.FININ fecha_ini
      ,td.BA33_DESC place
      ,tms.tms_util.getplazas_singuiachofer(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) as passengers
      ,row_number() over (partition by tg.FININ, td.BA33_DESC order by vu.fly) as rn
FROM TABLE(fnc_obtener_vuelos_guia(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO)) vu
    inner join tms.gui tg on (tg.fol = vu.fol and tg.prod = vu.producto and tg.FININ = vu.fecha_inicio)
    inner join tms.dgp td on (tg.fol = td.fol and tg.prod = td.prod)
where td.fol = :P10_FOLLETO
      and td.prod = :P10_PRODUCTO
      and tg.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO)
) 
PIVOT (MAX(fly) for rn in (1,2,3,4));
```

**--Update--**

You can use the anonymous block to fill in the cursor and then print it as follows. In your application, you can create the procedure and return the cursor.

```
SET SERVEROUT ON
DECLARE 
P_OUT_CUR SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN P_OUT_CUR FOR 'SELECT * FROM
        (SELECT vu.fly
              ,tg.FININ fecha_ini
              ,td.BA33_DESC place
              ,tms.tms_util.getplazas_singuiachofer(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) as passengers
              ,row_number() over (partition by tg.FININ, td.BA33_DESC order by vu.fly) as rn
        FROM TABLE(fnc_obtener_vuelos_guia(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO)) vu
            inner join tms.gui tg on (tg.fol = vu.fol and tg.prod = vu.producto and tg.FININ = vu.fecha_inicio)
            inner join tms.dgp td on (tg.fol = td.fol and tg.prod = td.prod)
        where td.fol = :P10_FOLLETO
              and td.prod = :P10_PRODUCTO
              and tg.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO) 
        PIVOT (MAX(fly) for rn in ('
                       || (
        SELECT
            LISTAGG(RN, ',') WITHIN GROUP(
                ORDER BY
                    RN
            )
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
                        PARTITION BY TG.FININ, TD.BA33_DESC
                        ORDER BY
                            VU.FLY
                    ) AS RN
                FROM
                    TABLE ( FNC_OBTENER_VUELOS_GUIA(:P10_FOLLETO, :P10_PRODUCTO, :P10_FECHA_INICIO) ) VU
                    INNER JOIN TMS.GUI TG ON ( TG.FOL = VU.FOL
                                               AND TG.PROD = VU.PRODUCTO
                                               AND TG.FININ = VU.FECHA_INICIO )
                    INNER JOIN TMS.DGP TD ON ( TG.FOL = TD.FOL
                                               AND TG.PROD = TD.PROD )
                WHERE
                    TD.FOL = :P10_FOLLETO
                    AND TD.PROD = :P10_PRODUCTO
                    AND TG.FININ = :P10_FECHA_INICIO
            )
    )
                       || '))'
        USING P10_FOLLETO, P10_PRODUCTO, P10_FECHA_INICIO, P10_FOLLETO, P10_PRODUCTO, P10_FECHA_INICIO, P10_FOLLETO, P10_PRODUCTO
        , P10_FECHA_INICIO;

dbms_sql.return_result(P_OUT_CUR); -- JUST TO PRINT THE RESULT OF THE CURSOR

END;
/
```

This code is not tested so you need to correct the code if you find silly errors.

Comment: and how could be the plsql to do it dynamically, because that is the problem that i have, i could have 1, 2 4 or 10 records. Regards